# Can a local Flash application change channels and get video out of a TV Tunner card?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need to show live television on a frame of my desktop application made with Flex.

Comment: So you want to access your tv-card and not a stream. If anything this could be done with AIR. Definitely not with a web app.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I said it was a desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash will not be able to control the card directly, especially when running in a web browser. But running something like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), it's not entirely impossible that you could pull this off. It can stream video from a tuner card and has a web-interface. 
That would offload the actual "tuning" and encoding to VLC and just have flash be the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Look for some red5 application here red5.org

or watch this one http://tv.adobe.com/watch/360flex-conference/advanced-video-streaming-mgmt-techs-with-flex-flash/

also
the better way is determine the type of streaming you have of your live television, then redirect it to your RTMP server (red5 or FMS) and then wathc it via flex/AIR client

Thank you
Eugene